# How to extract double from a stringstream

Tags: c++, double, stringstream

While working on my C++ project I've noticed something odd while playing with `stringstream` objects: I'm not able to extract a `double` from a `stringstream` using `>>`.

Consider this example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::string string("1000 ; 523277527397538 ; 0.183 ; 0.453 ; 0.5 ; 0.5 ; 0.033 ; 0 ; 0 ;");
    std::stringstream stringstream(string);
    int integer;
    char character;
    double doubleprec;
    stringstream >> integer >> character;
    stringstream >> integer >> character;
    stringstream >> doubleprec >> character;
    stringstream >> doubleprec >> character;

    return 0;
}
```

Using my debugger I've noticed that the variable `integer` takes first the value `1000` and then the value `523277527397538` (as I expected), but `doubleprec` takes always the value `0`.

Why is that? Am I missing something about how streams work?

Comment: @LogicStuff Do you mean which values `integer` takes after `stringstream >> integer >> character; stringstream >> integer >> character;` ?

Comment: What is `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` on your machine?

Comment: @LogicStuff Ah! Ok, now I understand what you meant. `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` on my machine is `2147483647` and of course `integer` doesn't take the value `523277527397538`. I was wrong. In order to have a variable take that value I need an `unsigned long`

Comment: Ah... Weird stuff... If I change `integer` from `int` to `unsigned long`, `doubleprec` takes the right values. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first stream output statement of:

```
stringstream >> integer >> character;
```

is successful. The remaining three are not due to the fact that your int variable can not hold the value of `523277527397538`. Change it to `long long`:

```
long long integer;
```

When stream extraction fails to put the `523277527397538` number literal to your variable then the stringstream's [failbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is set and subsequent calls to stringstream extraction also fail. A good approach is to use the `if` statement when working with stream IO:

```
if (stringstream >> integer >> character){
    // success
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why is this happening? Why the fact that `integer` can't contain the number makes `doubleprec` always `0` ?

Comment: @jackscorrow correct. the value 523277527397538 happens to be too large for an int on your machine. This causes the input stream to go into an error state

Comment: @jackscorrow "If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set" starting with C++11. [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Comment: @Rakete1111 So `doubleprec` is always `0` because `failbit` has been set, am I correct?

Comment: @jackscorrow No, `value` is set to `0` *and* `failbit` is set. One does not cause the other.

Comment: @jackscorrow On my machine it is never `0`. Since it is a local variable it has some noise value of `-9.2559631349317831e+061` and remains at that.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm sorry but I still can't understand why these two facts lead `doubleprec` to hold the wrong values. Why not just `integer` takes `0`?

Comment: The value of `doubleprec` is never updated because the statement of `stringstream >> doubleprec` fails to update it.

Comment: @Ron Oh! Thank you! Now I get it!

Comment: @Ron That's just because you are not compiling with C++11 or greater, because starting with C++11, the Standard mandates that it is set to `0`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I was testing this on VS 2013 which has C++11 support. Whether it is _turned on_ by default I don't know.

Comment: @Ron Well, VS in general doesn't really comply to a single Standard. It implements a bit of every Standard, which can be very confusing :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Even on Linux with a C++14 compiler it is not set to `0`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf865126e296996f).

Comment: @Ron Oh right, but if the value is too large, then it has another behavior, sorry. "If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and failbit flag is set."

Answer (score 2):

quick demo to reinforce Ron's answer: (c++14)

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    std::string string("1000 ; 523277527397538 ; 0.183 ; 0.453 ; 0.5 ; 0.5 ; 0.033 ; 0 ; 0 ;");
    std::stringstream stringstream(string);

    auto okfail = [](auto&& b) {
        if (not b) return std::string("fail");
        return std::string("ok");
    };

    auto read = [&](auto&& var, auto&& f) {
        std::cout << "reading " << var << ". Stream is " << okfail(stringstream) << std::endl;
        f();
        std::cout << "read " << var << ". Stream is " << okfail(stringstream) << std::endl;
    };

    int integer1;
    int integer2;
    char character;
    double doubleprec1, doubleprec2;
    read("integer1", [&] { stringstream >> integer1 >> character; });
    read("integer2", [&] { stringstream >> integer2 >> character; });
    read("doubleprec1", [&] { stringstream >> doubleprec1 >> character; });
    read("doubleprec2", [&] { stringstream >> doubleprec2 >> character; });

    std::cout << integer1<< " " << integer2 << " " << doubleprec1 << " " << doubleprec2 << " " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

example output (imac 64-bit):

```
reading integer1. Stream is ok
read integer1. Stream is ok
reading integer2. Stream is ok
read integer2. Stream is fail
reading doubleprec1. Stream is fail
read doubleprec1. Stream is fail
reading doubleprec2. Stream is fail
read doubleprec2. Stream is fail
1000 2147483647 0 0
```

now change integer2 to long int:

```
reading integer1. Stream is ok
read integer1. Stream is ok
reading integer2. Stream is ok
read integer2. Stream is ok
reading doubleprec1. Stream is ok
read doubleprec1. Stream is ok
reading doubleprec2. Stream is ok
read doubleprec2. Stream is ok
1000 523277527397538 0.183 0.453
```